# Need a flexible definition of a target dependencies in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to put two targets in a Makefile, `exec1` and `exec2`.  The dependencies for `exec1` should look like

```
exec1: aux1.o bal.o exec1.f90
bal.o: aux1.o bal.f90
```

and for `exec2` like

```
exec2: aux2.o bal.o exec1.f90
bal.o: aux2.o bal.f90
```

Long story short: I need `make` to understand that `bal.o` has different dependencies depending on whether `exec1` or `exec2` is being built.  How can I "explain" this in my Makefile?

The problem is that if I try to build `exec2`, it is imperative that aux1.o *not* be built.  The reason is that aux1.f90 has some modules of the same name as modules in aux2.f90, and if aux1.f90 gets compiled into aux1.o first, then the compilation of bal.f90 will get its modules from aux1.f90 instead of aux2.f90, which is what it really needs, and there will be mass confusion.

Comment: Suppose that you issue the build command `make exec1 exec2`. What do you expect to happen in this case? Do you expect the build merely to issue an error message and fail?

Comment: @thb In my particular code, the build proceeds without error, but when I try to run the code I get crashes.  After alot of poking and prodding I have narrowed it all down to the problem I mention in my post.  I suppose that for some codes, a build wouldn't even work in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use separate `Makefile` and use target-dependent `Makefile` ("recursively").

The main `Makefile`:

```
exec1 exec2:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.$@
```

And you have `Makefile.exec1`:

```
exec1: aux1.o bal.o exec1.f90
    @echo "$^ => $@"

bal.o: aux1.o bal.f90
    @echo "$^ => $@"
```

And `Makefile.exec2` too:

```
exec2: aux2.o bal.o exec1.f90
    @echo "$^ => $@"

bal.o: aux2.o bal.f90
    @echo "$^ => $@"
```

The test (after `touch aux2.o bal.f90`):

```
$ gmake -s exec1
aux1.o bal.f90 => bal.o
aux1.o bal.o exec1.f90 => exec1
$ gmake -s exec2
aux2.o bal.f90 => bal.o
aux2.o bal.o exec1.f90 => exec2
```

(I'm using FreeBSD and on it the GNU make is `gmake` - assume you use GNU make, and the `-s` suppress its "debug"-messages).

I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: I'm glad you like it :)

Comment: In a large project, it's going to be a problem. Check out "Recursive Make Considered Harmful"(http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 2):

Pure GNU make solution:

```
exec1: aux1.o bal.o exec1.f90

bal.o: $(if $(filter exec1,${MAKECMDGOALS}),aux1.o,aux2.o) bal.f90
# It will fail if someone will try building BOTH `exec1` and `exec2`
# If you care about this case, let's put some safeguards in:
ifeq ($words $(filter exec1 exec2,${MAKECMDGOALS}),2)
  $(error You cannot build exec1 and exec2 simultaneously)
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The `make` command finds many interesting, unexpected uses. Yours is one.

It would be neatest if you could separately build `bal1.o` and `bal2.o`, but I suppose that this will not serve your case, or you would hardly have asked the question.

In your situation, I would try this: build `bal1.o` and `bal2.o` separately, *even though this (by itself) will not serve your case.* Then, under the tab-indented build commands, temporarily make a symbolic link named `bal.o`, the link pointing either to `bal1.o` or to `bal2.o`. Once the link has done its duty, delete it.

For example:

```
exec1: aux1.o bal1.o exec1.f90; rm -f aux2.o && ln -s bal1.o bal.o && command-to-build-exec1 && rm bal.o
bal1.o: aux1.o bal.f90
.PHONY: bal.o
```

(The `.PHONY` line is least important. You can omit it, but if your `make` is GNU Make, then it informs GNU Make that no actual file `bal.o` will be built.)

The semicolon `;` can be replaced by a newline followed by a horizontal tab if you wish, but I do not know how to make Stack Overflow correctly represent the tab character. The semicolon works.

Of course, you will replace `command-to-build-exec1` by whatever that command is in your particular case.

Comment: In view of the information I have from you, my answer should point you in the right direction. You may need to adapt it further to your specific case. Makefiles can be fun, too much fun sometimes. Good luck.